# Run function after download begins Javascript

Tags: javascript, download, triggers, detect

Is it possible to detect download in the browser, and run a function when the download starts?

Comment: Well it's possible to listen for clicks on `<a>` elements...

Comment: I thought of that but I actually want to trigger the function when the download is detected. If something goes wrong and the download doesnt start, I dont want to run the function.

Comment: @Shabbb How is "download" implemented ? Can include `html`, `js` ?

Comment: Yes. It includes HTML

Comment: @Shabbb, the comments are asking for addition information; this narrows the scope of the problem, increasing the chances of getting a good answer. Personally I don't know how to trigger a script when a download starts or even if it is possible, but I am interested. However, *"detect download in browser"* is to broad a statement, it needs to be narrowed.